# How do I load data using NSEntityDescription?

Tags: iphone, ios5, xcode4.3

i am new in xcode. i hope someone will teach me more xcode.

i'm learning core data now, from what i learn, i can save my data from uitextfield using uibutton. this is my code.

```
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender
{
    TestSaveDataAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    Highscore *record = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Highscore" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    record.highscore1 = textField.text;
    NSLog(@"Saved for %@", textField.text);
    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }
```

now i have a UILabel call label and a button2 next to it. how do i load my data in my label when button2 is pushed? Please teach me.

i already wrote like this but i dont know how to put it in my label. any tutorial that i find only put it in tableview. i don't want to put it in tableview, i just want my data show in my label.

```
- (IBAction)button2:(id)sender
{
    TestSaveDataAppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    NSManagedObjectContext *context = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Highscore" inManagedObjectContext:context];
    [request setEntity:entity];
    NSError *error;
    if (![context save:&error])
    {
        NSLog(@"Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add [NSPredicate](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSPredicate_Class/Reference/NSPredicate.html) to your request and execute it.

```
    NSPredicate *predicate = <#create your predicate here#>;
    [request setPredicate:predicate];

    NSError *error;
    NSArray *results = [context executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
    if (error) {
        //inform user
    }
    //if you found something, you can set text for your UILabel
    if ([results count]) {
        Highscore *record = [results objectAtIndex:0];
        label.text = record.highscore1;
    }
```